# List of datatype variable in class won't be updated

Tags: c#, list, class

i've create a class having List as a property
here's the code

```
public class ScreenEventNTF
{
    //property
    public List<string> list_event_string { get; set; }

    //constructor
    public ScreenEventNTF(blah blah)
    {
       list_event_string = new List<string>();
    }

    // the not-working method
    public void AddToStringTodraw(string string_inp)
    {
        list_event_string.Add(string_inp);

    }

}
```

from the main class i do something like

```
ScreenEventNTF notifier = new ScreenEventNTF(blah blah);
notifier.AddToStringTodraw("Fabulous");
```

and i try to write all the string in notifier.list_event_string  but it didn't seem to
have any value stored in the List

here's the code  according to the coments.

```
foreach (string text in notifier.list_event_string)
 spriteBatch.DrawString(font_test, text , 
                vector_mouse, Color.White, 0f, Vector2.Zero, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 1.0f);
```

what am i doing wrong ??

please help me, any help will be appreciate.

Comment: Your displayed code does not demonstrate the problem. Mind adding an example that actually produces the issue?

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint on your AddToStringTodraw method, and make sure it's added properly to the list, and that what you print is what you think you print.

Comment: how do you read a data from the list?

Comment: Your code as is shown works fine except your constructor params.  I was able to get your list to output count as shown here http://pastebin.com/qNdKt834

Comment: i'm taking my time to see the code again. i started the thread since i thought it was a problem because of referece type matter or something like that.    thanks for all the answer ... now i see the probelm shold be from other part.

Comment: hm.. what if instead `text` you (say) write `"<--->"`. Will  this be printed in a way and place you expect ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you add to the list should work, and I think that it does work but the problem is that when you draw the string you either:

1. Draw in a location off-screen: check the value in vector_mouse
2. You're drawing white text. Is the background contrast enough?

You can say that the method isn't working if it is indeed called and there are no values present in the list. You can just confirm with the debugger, set a breakpoint just before the foreach (string...)

Also, if you're not using scale, rotation as I can see from your parameters, you can just use this overload of the DrawString method: [DrawString(SpriteFont, string, Vector2, Color)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433981.aspx)

Finally, if the List field is public, why should you expose the add functionality in a separate method? That's not necessary unless there are going to be changes in encapsulation in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly how are you iterating through the list?  Need to see the code that prints the elements in the List object.